# Javascript: multi-tiered conditional, use of "return false" stopping later conditional checks

Tags: javascript, return, conditional-statements

Return false isn't doing quite what I want it to do. I want it to prevent the form submit if any one of the conditionals passes, but I still want it to proceed down the tree of conditionals. Right now if the first conditional `if ($(".item.active").length == 0) {` passes, it hits the `return false;` and stops the later conditionals from checking.

How can I rewrite this to work better?

```
$('#go').click(function() {

    function invalidBtn(){
        $('#go').addClass('invalid');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#go').removeClass('invalid');
        }, 5000)
    }

    $('.error').remove();
    $('.invalid').removeClass('invalid');

    if ($(".item.active").length == 0) {
        $(".item:first-of-type").before('<h5 class="error">Select a shirt type</h5>');
        invalidBtn();
        return false;

    } else {

        if ( $(".item.active .size-select .active").length == 0) {
            $('.item.active .size-select').before("<div class='error'>Select a size</div>").addClass("invalid");
            //$(this).addClass('invalid');
            invalidBtn();
            return false;
        }

        if ($(".item.active .gender-select").length > 0 ) {
            if ( $(".item.active .gender-select .active").length == 0 ){
                $('.item.active .gender-select').before("<div class='error'>Select a gender</div>").addClass("invalid");
                //$(this).addClass('invalid');
                invalidBtn();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( !$('#fn-field').val() ) {
        $('#fn-field').before("<div class='error'>Enter your first name</div>").addClass("invalid");
        //$(this).addClass('invalid');
        invalidBtn();
        return false;
    }

    if ( !$('#ln-field').val() ) {
        $('#ln-field').before("<div class='error'>Enter your last name</div>").addClass("invalid");
        //$(this).addClass('invalid');
        invalidBtn();
        return false;
    }

});
```

Thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply replace all of your return false to change a boolean, and return the boolean, like this:

```
$('#go').click(function() {

function invalidBtn(){
    $('#go').addClass('invalid');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#go').removeClass('invalid');
    }, 5000)
}

var retVal = true;

$('.error').remove();
$('.invalid').removeClass('invalid');

if ($(".item.active").length == 0) {
    $(".item:first-of-type").before('<h5 class="error">Select a shirt type</h5>');
    invalidBtn();
    retVal = false;

} else {

    if ( $(".item.active .size-select .active").length == 0) {
        $('.item.active .size-select').before("<div class='error'>Select a size</div>").addClass("invalid");
        //$(this).addClass('invalid');
        invalidBtn();
        retVal = false;
    }

    if ($(".item.active .gender-select").length > 0 ) {
        if ( $(".item.active .gender-select .active").length == 0 ){
            $('.item.active .gender-select').before("<div class='error'>Select a gender</div>").addClass("invalid");
            //$(this).addClass('invalid');
            invalidBtn();
            retVal = false;
        }
    }
}

if ( !$('#fn-field').val() ) {
    $('#fn-field').before("<div class='error'>Enter your first name</div>").addClass("invalid");
    //$(this).addClass('invalid');
    invalidBtn();
    retVal = false;
}

if ( !$('#ln-field').val() ) {
    $('#ln-field').before("<div class='error'>Enter your last name</div>").addClass("invalid");
    //$(this).addClass('invalid');
    invalidBtn();
    retVal = false;
}

return retVal;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Return false isn't doing quite what I want it to do. I want it to prevent the form submit if any one of the conditionals passes, but I still want it to proceed down the tree of conditionals. Right now if the first conditional if ($(".item.active").length == 0) { passes, it hits the return false; and stops the later conditionals from checking.

Right, because `return` exits the function.

If you want to keep going through the code following it, don't use return, set a variable you return at the end. E.g.:

```
var valid = true;

if (someInvalidCondition) {
    // ...do anyting condition-specific...
    valid = false;
}
if (someOtherInvalidCondition) {
    // ...do anyting condition-specific...
    valid = false;
}
// Rinse, repeat

// Done
return valid;
```

Or I usually like to return a count of the errors. Or a list (array) of the errors. Etc.